# How to design a store in Vuex to handle clicks in nested, custom components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to design a store to manage the events of my Vuex application. This far, I have the following.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
Vue.use(Vuex);

const state = { dataRows: [], activeDataRow: {} };
const mutations = {
    UPDATE_DATA(state, data) { state.dataRows = data; state.activeDataRow = {}; },
};

export default new Vuex.Store({ state, mutations });
```

I'm going to have a number of list items that are supposed to change the value of the data in the store when clicked. The design of the root component *App* and the menu bar *Navigation* is as follows (there will be a bunch of actions in the end so I've collected them in the file *actions.js*).

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <navigation></navigation>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import navigation from "./navigation.vue"
export default { components: { navigation } }
</script>

<template>
  <div id="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li onclick="console.log('Clickaroo... ');">Plain JS</li>
      <li @click="updateData">Action Vuex</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import { updateData } from "../vuex_app/actions";
  export default {
    vuex: {
      getters: { activeDataRow: state => state.activeDataRow }, 
      actions: { updateData }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Clicking on the first list item shows the output in the console. However, when clicking on the second one, there's nothing happening, so I'm pretty sure that the event isn't dispatched at all. I also see following error when the page's being rendered:

> Property or method "updateData" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

I'm very new to Vuex so I'm only speculating. Do I need to put in reference to the *updateData* action in the store, alongside with *state* and *mutations*? How do I do that? What/where's the "data option" that the error message talks about? Isn't it my components state and it's properties?

Comment: Could you share your `updateData()` action?

Comment: @El_Matella It's empty. I can add *console.log("!");* to it if it makes any difference. What were you considering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why the error

You are getting the error, because when you have `<li @click="updateData">` in the template, it looks for a method `updateData` in the vue component which it does not find, so it throws the error. To resolve this, you need to add corresponding methods in the vue component like following:

```
<script>
  import { updateData } from "../vuex_app/actions";
  export default {
    vuex: {
      getters: { activeDataRow: state => state.activeDataRow }, 
      actions: { updateData }
    }, 
    methods:{ 
      updateData: () => this.$store.dispatch("updateData")    
    }
  }
</script>
```

What `this.$store.dispatch("updateData")` is doing is calling your vuex actions as documented [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html).

### What/where's the "data option"

You don't have any data properties defined, data properties for a vue component can be used, if you want to use that only in that component. If you have data which needs to be accessed across multiple components, you can use [vuex state](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html) as I believe you are doing.

Following is the way to have [data properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data) for a vue component:

```
<script>
  import { updateData } from "../vuex_app/actions";
  export default {
    date: {
      return {
        data1 : 'data 1',
        data2 : {
            nesteddata: 'data 2' 
          }
      }
    }
    vuex: {
      getters: { activeDataRow: state => state.activeDataRow }, 
      actions: { updateData }
    }, 
    methods:{ 
      updateData: () => this.$store.dispatch("updateData")    
    }
  }
</script>
```

You can use these data properties in the views, have [computed properies](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#computed) based on it, or create [watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) on it and many [more](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data).

Comment: It's getting brighter and clearer for each of your replies. The confusion was totally due to my ignorance of the area. Still not there, though, but soon, hehe. One follow-up - I've noticed that my *this* is undefined. So fetching the *$store* fails due to that. Could it be something basic? (I'll compose a question on that particular subject in a few minutes, unless you'll see something fairly apparent.)

Comment: In case you feel like a challenge and extra rep - [go nuts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895694/the-context-of-this-not-provided-to-the-modules-exporting), mate.