# The context of this not provided to the modules exporting

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

*I'm displeased with the formulation of the question. Feel encouraged to suggest an improvement. Also, please keep in mind that due to ignoyance (ignorance leading to annoyance), I might have flawed diagnostics of hte issue. Sorry about that.*

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40893583/1525840) it's suggested to use `this.$store.xxx` and it fails in my code because `this` is undefined. I strongly suspect something stupid being done by the author of the code (that would be me), so I'll present the schematics of my component layout.

The way it's intended is that I have a landing page *index.js* that creates two components - one for the visuals of the application and one for the storage of information. The visual *App* will consist of a navigation bar (and a rendering area later on). The navbar will dispatch commands to the store (and to the viewing area) rendering different *.vue files showing tables, lists etc.

So, how come I get to see the text *this is undefined*? Is my structure entirely flawed or am I just missing a small detail here and there?

**index.js**

```
import Vue from "vue"
import Store from "./vuex_app/store"
import App from "./vuex_modules/app.vue"
new Vue({ el: "#app-base", components: { App }, store: Store });
```

**store.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
Vue.use(Vuex);
const state = { ... };
const mutations = { ... };
export default new Vuex.Store({ state, mutations });
```

**app.vue**

```
<template><div id="app">App component<navigation></navigation></div></template>
<script>
import navigation from "./navigation.vue"
export default { components: { navigation } }
</script>
```

**navigation.vue**

```
<template><div id="nav-bar"><p v-on:click="updateData">Update</p></div></template>
<script>
import { updateData } from "../vuex_app/actions";
export default {
  vuex: {
    actions: { updateData },
    getters: { ... }
  },
  methods: {
    updateData: () => { 
      console.log("this is " + this);
      this.$store.dispatch("updateData");
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**actions.js**

```
export const updateData = ({dispatch}, data) => { 
  console.log("invoked updateData"); 
  dispatch("UPDATE_DATA", data); 
};
```

Comment: Possible `Don't use arrow functions on an instance property ... As arrow functions are bound to the parent context, this will not be the Vue instance as you’d expect and this.myMethod will be undefined.` per [link](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html)   Could that be it? Oh, and thanks for this posting.. it's got me investigating vue.js...

Comment: @zipzit Glad to be of service to your curiosity, hehe. And thanks for +1, too. I'll look into the this'ish part right away but in any case, it seems weird to me that *this* is *undefined*. I can see how it **differs** from the expected value but to be **nothing**...?

Comment: @zipzit I owe you a pizza. That **was** the problem with *this*. There might be more - I haven't tested the whole flow yet - but it's definitely a good shot. Now, if you can shed some feelings about the architecture of my setup, I'm all ears. Or, rather, all eyes.

Comment: Is your problem solved related of `this` here? One question why you have vex: { ... } inside navigation.vue when you have already attached your store to Vue app in index.js?

Comment: Regarding the whole setup, it overall looks good to me. You can see more examples [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples), especially this [one](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples/shopping-cart) which is more similar to yours. You can also generate a scaffold from [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) and see its structure, which I believe is quite same as yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) offers a pretty nice reactive type, minimalist JavaScript framework.   Unfortunately, per [this link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) there may be some unusual usage requirements.  In this case,

> Don’t use arrow functions on an instance property or callback (e.g.
> vm.$watch('a', newVal => this.myMethod())). As arrow functions are
> bound to the parent context, `this` will not be the Vue instance as
> you’d expect and `this.myMethod` will be undefined.

Comment: I've found even other info on their web page (which I must have missed due to mental overload first time there). It's said clearly that Vue isn't an MVC framework but rather MVVM. I was **not** aware of that. Thanks, mate!